# REACTJS Add a condition to .map to check if the element is contained in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm starting on reactJS. I try to check if my userId is contained in an array To display them if they are present in array.

Here is my code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const RequestTeam = ({ userData }) => {
    function ListItem(props) {
        return <li>{props.value}</li>
    }

    function RequestList(props) {
        const teams = props.teams;
        const listItems = teams.map((team) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < userData.waitList.length; i++) {
                if (userData === teams.requestUser[i]) {
                    return <ListItem key={team._id} value={team.name} />
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        );
        return (
            <ul>
                {listItems}
            </ul>
        );
    }

    const teamsData = useSelector((state) => state.teamsReducer);

    return (
        <RequestList teams={teamsData} />
    )
};

export default RequestTeam;
```

but i encounter an error :

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

I've been blocking on it for a few hours. What's going on ?

Comment: Check the value of `teams.waitList[i]`. `waitList` is not an array.

Comment: in my database it is an array

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your data (teams) is fetched before this component being rendered, because React doesn't wait for it, and tries to render component as fast as possible. If data is undefined, you cannot use related to this data methods etc.

For this you can simply use if statement like this

```
if(teamsData) {
    render <RequestList teams={teamsData} />
} else {
    render <div>Loading...</div>
}
```

...or `{ ? : }` expression

Comment: I tried but it still doesn't work, i have already : ×
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined